# App Submission fails but bug cannot be reproduced in debug mode in Corona SDK

Tags: ios, coronasdk, appstore-approval, release-builds

We are having this weird issue related to submitting our app on iOS. 
Basically when we build ( using developer profile ) and test ( via test flight ) everything works fine as expected even with most extensive test cases.

But when build ( using iOS distribution profile ) and submitted to apple ... in the review process it fails to pass due to a bug which we CANNOT REPRODUCE.

So, my best guess is that the bug/error is only happening in the release build ( probably due to code optimisation ) .. but I can't even know where and what to look for if I can't reproduce ?

I have submitted it the app twice so far ( with possible guess and fix ) and both time it came back with same error.

How do I test or even see the logs using a release build ? ( so far the DTS has been useless in providing any useful information)

/*EDITED*/

A bit more background info:
This is a game application made with Corona SDK. If you're familiar with corona sdk then you know what a scene is.

So basically,

1. I have a "home scene" I have an "open" button on my scene.
2. I click on the open button a spinner shows up->the app reads a json
   file->goes to the next scene.

What apple is seeing in the review process is: Upon clicking on the "open button" on "home scene" the spinner shows up and it does not do anything further. Hence, the app is failing to pass apple's review process.

Please note: this only happens in the release mode (that is built with distribution profile) and not in debug mode ( that is built with provisioning profile )... thus I am unable to reproduce.

Comment: You mights try giving some details of what is going wrong when "it fails".

Comment: Apple test your app in release mode, so you can check if it crash in release mode. (also you can enable the Zombie Objects to test if any findings)

Comment: HI Z.Y, thanks for replying. Unfortunately I dont understand what you are proposing. How can I test a .app or .iap that is built in release mode ? I am unaware of such procedure. Perhaps you can shed some light on it. Please note: the app was built using Corona SDK and not XCode.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have added more information in the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, if your App was rejected due to a crash, **Apple will send you the crash logs**.  And they'll crash it multiple times and send you multiple logs.

Now then, there are two ways to view crash logs for release build versions of apps.

1. On your device, open Settings.  Choose General > About > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostics & Usage Data.  This will be a list of files.  Some of them should be your crash logs.
2. If you plug your phone into a computer after a crash, the crash logs are moved on to the computer.

The location is OS-specific.

- On Mac OSX: `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<device name>/`
- On Win XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Apple
  computer\Logs\CrashReporter\<device name>\`
- On Win 7:
  `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Apple
  computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<device name>\`

And finally, your IDE almost definitely has a way of browsing the on-device crash logs.  I'm not familiar with any non-Xcode IDEs for developing iOS apps so I can't give any specific advice--but look around.  Surely there's something.

Comment: nhgrif .. thanks for your reply. As I have mentioned in the problem description that the error can not be reproduced in debug mode which is using provisioning profile, it only happens in release mode when apple reviews it. So there's no way of me getting any log unless apple provides it ( which they're not ). 
I cannot install release built of the app on device because it is built with distribution profile. If there's one can you please provides steps to do that ?

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with debug mode, release mode only.  You can install release version of app with iTunes.

Comment: thanks @nhgrif.
I re-did the adhoc distribution and build my app again and looked in the console of the device from XCode Organizer. That revealed the error. Basically it's silently failing to load one of the images. I said silently because it's not crashing, just not moving on to the next scene. Weird. I faced this before but last time it was not so silent.

Comment: For the record.. apple did not send any crash logs perhaps because the app never crashed. That's why I was having difficulties on where or at which point it's failing as I've described in my question.

Comment: I thought you said you submitted to the app store and Apple rejected due to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should also ask Apple to send you the console log from the run.  Problems most likely will show up there.

Secondly, you should test using an AdHoc Distribution profile as well.